# can I trash my mail folder

Tags: macos

My mail folder is using a lot of memory.  Can I simply empty the folder in the Application Support folder or do I have to throw mail in the trash using the Mail program?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: **don't delete anything in `~/Library`**. Those are private folders used by apps to save configuration and data.

The `~/Library/Application Support/Mail` folder in particular holds configuration files.

Don't delete `~/Library/Mail` either, if your mail provider uses POP3 you'll lose all mail, if your mail provider uses IMAP the Mail app will have to download messages and attachments again.

To free up disk space delete mails you no longer need and then simply empty the trash:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This article should help you manage your mail storage, deletion, and batch deletion issues: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11732. Advanced: Be wary that erasing mail on a client for IMAP can erase the server copy too.

Comment: Answers can contain links, but should stand on their own in case the link breaks.